# String is unexpectedly converted to hex

Tags: ruby, firebird

I tried to get some data from Firebird database. I have a field `"UID"`, whose value is `de6c50a94aee524d9d287a43158360f4` String(16).

When I get it with Ruby, I got:

```
"UID"=>"\xDElP\xA9J\xEERM\x9D(zC\x15\x83`\xF4"
```

Why didn't I get a string?

```
conn.query(:hash , 'SELECT FIRST 1 UID FROM cmd').first
```

Comment: What is the datatype and characterset in the database (my guess is `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS` which is a binary type).

Answer (score 2):

The `UID` you receive is a binary array, which in ruby is represented as a [packed](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-unpack) string. To unpack it do the following:

```
"\xDElP\xA9J\xEERM\x9D(zC\x15\x83`\xF4".unpack('n*').map { |x| x.to_s(16) }.join
# => "de6c50a94aee524d9d287a43158360f4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your UID is a 128bit value. The hex string representation of `UID` can be built with [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
str = "%08x%04x%04x%04x%04x%08x" % UID.unpack("NnnnnN")
=> "de6c50a94aee524d9d287a43158360f4"
```

The reason for the specific formatting is this code is really for UUID's

```
str = "%08x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%08x" % UID.unpack("NnnnnN")
=> "de6c50a9-4aee-524d-9d28-7a43158360f4"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I guess the datatype of `UID` in your Firebird database is a `CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS`, this is a binary datatype. Firebird (before Firebird 4) doesn't know the SQL types `BINARY` or `VARBINARY`, but fields with `CHARACTER SET OCTETS` are binary.

The value you are retrieving is probably a UUID. You either need to use the value as a binary, or select a human 'readable' UUID string using [UUID_TO_CHAR](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-uuid-to-char):

```
SELECT FIRST 1 UUID_TO_CHAR(UID) FROM cmd
```